# linear fractional transformations fixing a line

Tags: complex-analysis, conformal-geometry

I want to find all linear fractional transformations that fix the points 1 and -1. In particular i'd like to give this set a group structure and see if it is some familiar group or not. I wrote conditions for such $f$:

$$f(z)=\frac{az+b}{cz+d}$$

and i found

$$a+b-c-d=0$$
$$a-b+c-d=0$$
which give $a=d$ and $b=c$, thus the determinant of associated matrix is $a^2-b^2$. And now, how can i go on?

Comment: An alternative way to solve your question is to consider the  subgroup of linear fractional transformations fixing $0$ and $\infty$, which is isomorphic to your group.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function $f$ does not change if you scale the coefficients by a constant, so you can just as well assume that $a^2-b^2=1$.

But this gives (after scaling by $-1$ if necessary) the hyperbolic rotations $$\begin{pmatrix} \cosh x & \sinh x \\ \sinh x & \cosh x \end{pmatrix}.$$

Now, you can just have a look at the change of $x$ when you multiply two matrices to understand the group structure.

Comment: the additive group of complex numbers?